# AngularJS - grabbing specific data from an JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

Here is a picture of what the API is returning:

[image]

I am trying to create variables that grab the "Current Approver" and "Status" from this array. And if the "Current Approver" matches the username stored in local storage and the "Status" is "REJECTED" then I want to run a line of jquery.

Here is what I have:

```
$http.get( API + '/car' ).
success(function(data) {
  $scope.myCars = data;
  console.log(data);

  var originator = $scope.myCars["My CARs"]["Current Approver"],
      status = $scope.myCars["My CARs"].Status,
      user = localStorage.getItem('user') || null

  // Check if logged in user is originator and CAR is "REJECTED"
  if (originator === user && status === 'REJECTED') {
    $('#termCar').css('display', 'block');
  }

});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="car in myCars['My CARs']" class="myCar">
  <div class="carId">{{ car['Display Name'] }}</div>
  <div class="title">{{ car['Project Title'] }}</div>
  <div id="termCar" class="termCar"><a ui-sref="taskDetails">Terminate</a></div>
</div>
```

I know that it has something to do with these lines (obviously):

```
originator = $scope.myCars["My CARs"]["Current Approver"],
status = $scope.myCars["My CARs"].Status
```

I just cant figure out how to pull specific data out of an array i guess.

I need to be able to loop through the array of objects and find the ones that meet that if statement and then if one of those does then run the jQuery line.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
originator = $scope.myCars["My CARs"][0]["Current Approver"];
status = $scope.myCars["My CARs"][0].Status
```

You're simply not referencing which index in the array you wish to grab the values from.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the issue is this:

```
$scope.myCars["My CARs"]["Current Approver"]
```

For that to work, your data structure would have to look like this:

```
"My CARS": {
  "Current Approver": "..."
}
```

`My CARs` is an array of objects, so you need to iterate over that array. You would typically do this with a basic forEach. Lodash makes this nice to do, but I'll use native js:

```
var user = localStorage.getItem('user');
$http.get('/car').success(function(data) {
  var cars = data['My CARs'];
  cars.forEach(function(car) {
    if (car["Current Approver"] === user && car.Status === 'REJECTED') {
      // do stuff
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to filter the array `My CARs` to match the local user

```
$http.get(API + '/car').success(function(data) {
    $scope.myCars = data;
    console.log(data);
    var user = localStorage.getItem('user') || null;
    var originator = $scope.myCars["My CARs"].filter(function(d) {
        return d["Current Approver"] === user && d["Status"] === 'REJECTED'
    });

    if (originator.length) {
        $('#termCar').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var cars = $scope.myCars["My CARs"];
for(int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    var theCar = cars[i]; 
    if(theCar["Current Approver"] === user && theCar["Status"] === "REJECTED") {
        originator = theCar["Current Approver"];
        status = theCar.Status;
        break;
    }
}
```

This will give you the status of the first car that matches whose `Current Approver` matches the `user`.